# How to cast a list of inheriting objects to a collection of objects in Java?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I've a collection type:

```
Collection<A> collecA
```

And I've a list in my object:

```
List<B> listB
```

Where B is extending A

```
class B extends A { ... }
```

But I can't do the following:

```
collecA = listB
```

I can't understand why since Collection is implemented by List.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's assume for a moment you could do what you describe:

```
class B extends A { ... }

Collection<A> collecA;
List<B> listB;

collecA = listB;  // normally an error, but lets pretend its allowed

collecA.add(new A()); // PROBLEM!
```

The method call `collecA.add(new A())` appears okay since `collecA` is a collection
that holds `A`s.  However, if the above assignment were allowed, then we have a
problem because`collecA` is really reference to a `List<B>` instance - I just
added an `A` into a list that can only hold `B`s!

Asker also said:

> I can't understand why since Collection is implemented by List.

It doesn't matter that Collection is a superclass of List.  This assignment is illegal even if you used two lists.

```
class B extends A { ... }
List<A> listA;
List<B> listB;
listA = listB;  // still an error, still leads to the same problem
```

**The key is that the `List<A>` *variable* can reference only `List`s that can hold `A`s.  However, a `List<B>` *instance* cannot hold `A`s.  Therefore, a `List<A>` *variable* like `listA` cannot be assigned a reference to a `List<B>` *instance* referred to by`listB`.**

Or more generally speaking: *`B` being a subclass of `A` does **not** imply that `SomeGenericClass<B>` is a subclass of `SomeGenericClass<A>`* ([JLS §4.10](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10): *Subtyping does not extend through generic types: `T <: U` does not imply that `C<T> <: C<U>`.*)

---

It was this example/analogy from the *Java Generics Tutorial* that helped me understand this:

> http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

"Understanding why becomes much easier if you think of tangible objects — things you can actually picture — such as a cage:

```
// A cage is a collection of things, with bars to keep them in.
interface Cage<E> extends Collection<E>;
...
Cage<Lion> lionCage = ...;
Cage<Butterfly> butterflyCage = ...;
```

But what about an "animal cage"? English is ambiguous, so to be precise let's assume we're talking about an **"all-animal cage"**:

```
Cage<Animal> animalCage = ...;
```

This is a cage designed to hold all kinds of animals, **mixed together**. It must have bars strong enough to hold in the lions, and spaced closely enough to hold in the butterflies.
...
Since a lion is a kind of animal (Lion is a subtype of Animal), the question then becomes, "Is a lion cage a kind of animal cage? Is `Cage<Lion>` a subtype of `Cage<Animal>`?". By the above definition of animal cage, the answer must be "no". This is surprising! But it makes perfect sense when you think about it: A lion cage cannot be assumed to keep in butterflies, and a butterfly cage cannot be assumed to hold in lions. Therefore, neither cage can be considered an "all-animal" cage:

```
animalCage = lionCage;  // compile-time error
animalCage = butterflyCage; // compile-time error
```

"

Comment: Good easy to understand explanation Bert. I've always appreciated silly analogies when trying to understand Generics and inheritance. Kartoch should check this out.

Comment: @Tamon - Glad you (and hopefully others) found it easy to understand.  I had the same problem understanding generics and inheritance (not to mention generic wildcards), so it took a novel  example like in the Java Generics Tutorial to ingrain it in my head. I took a search for 'java generic cast animal cage' to remember exactly where I read this analogy. :-)

Answer (score 10):

```
Collection<? extends A> collecA
```

This fixes it. The problem is not the `List extends Collection`, but the generic types instead.

Answer (score 5):

Java generics are not *covariant*.

See [Java Theory and Practice: Generics Gotchas](https://web.archive.org/web/20080708230945/http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/java/java-theory-generic-050323/page2.html) for further details.

The page shows a simple example that would havoc the type-system if it was covariant:

> Imagine you could assign a List<Integer> to a List<Number>. Then the following code would allow you to put something that wasn't an Integer into a List<Integer>:

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> ln = li; // illegal
ln.add(new Float(3.1415)); // ERROR: Adds a float to list, which is a list of Integers!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign List<B> to Collection<B>, but not List<B> to Collection<A>.

Imagine what would happen if this were possible:

```
List<B> = new ArrayList<B>();
Collection<A> collecA = listB; //Assume that this line compiles
collecA.add(new A());
B item = listB.get(0); //ClassCastException!
```

As you see, we "fooled" the generics type system, by adding an instance of concrete type A to a collection that was supposed to have only objects of type B (or descendants).
As a consequence, the last line which performs an implicit cast to B fails with a ClassCastException. What's wrong with it? The compiler can't guarantee type safety, and that's against one of the Java generics principles.

Therefore, it has been decided that List<B> is Collection<B>, but NOT List<A> (or Collection<A>).

As a side comment, it is interesting to note that arrays don't follow the same rules: String[] **is** an Object[], and assignments are legal.