# What is the difference between <E extends Number> and <Number>?

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between this method declaration:

```
public static <E extends Number> List<E> process(List<E> nums){
```

and

```
 public static List<Number> process(List<Number> nums){
```

Where would you use the former?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The first allows `process` of a `List<Integer>`, a `List<Double>`, etc. The second doesn't.

Generics in Java are invariant. They're not covariant like arrays.

That is, in Java, `Double[]` is a subtype of `Number[]`, but a `List<Double>` is NOT a subtype of `List<Number>`. A `List<Double>`, however, is a `List<? extends Number>`.

There are good reasons for generics being invariant, but that's also why the `extends` and `super` type are often necessary for subtyping flexibility.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Generics/Subtyping](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)

  - Explains why generics invariance is a good thing
- [More fun with wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)

  - Explains some uses of `super` and `extends` for bounded wildcards
- [Java Generics: What is PECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

  - This discusses the "Producer `extends` Consumer `super`" principle
  - *Effective Java 2nd Edition*, Item 28: Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility

Comment: I think it would be good also to explain the difference in case we have a method like this : `<E extends Number> E process(E elt)` vs `Number process(Number elt)`

Answer (score 16):

The *latter method* (the one *without* `<E extends Number>`) will only accept a parameter of exactly type `List<Number>` and will it always
return a `List<Number>`.  For example, it will **not** accept `List<Integer>`.

The *former method* (the one *with* `<E extends Number>`) is a **[generic method](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)**, meaning it can accept different types of `List`s
and it will return the same type of `List`, as long as the `List`s are lists of *something* that
extends `Number`, e.g. `List<Integer>`.

Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProcessGenerics {

    List<Number>  listNumber  = new ArrayList<Number>();
    List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Double>  listDouble  = new ArrayList<Double>();


    public static
        List<Number> processWithoutExtends(List<Number> nums){ return nums; }

    List<Number>  resultN = processWithoutExtends(listNumber);  // OK
  //List<Integer> resultI = processWithoutExtends(listInteger); // compile-error - method not applicable
  //List<Double>  resultD = processWithoutExtends(listDouble);  // compile-error - method not applicable


    public static <E extends Number>
        List<E> processWithExtends(List<E> nums){ return nums; }

    List<Number>  resultN2 = processWithExtends(listNumber);  // OK
    List<Integer> resultI2 = processWithExtends(listInteger); // OK
    List<Double>  resultD2 = processWithExtends(listDouble);  // OK

}
```

See a similar explanation in the Wildcards chapter in the Generics Lesson in the Java Tutorials:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

See also *[How to cast a list of inheriting objects to a collection of objects in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754756/how-to-cast-a-list-of-inheriting-objects-to-a-collection-of-objects-in-java)*  Both questions are really about generics and subtypes, e.g. whether `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `List<Number>` (it's not!!!).