# Class<T> and static method Class.forName() drive me crazy

Tags: java, generics, reflection

this code doesn't compile. I'm wondering what I am doing wrong:

```
private static Importable getRightInstance(String s) throws Exception {
 Class<Importable> c = Class.forName(s);
 Importable i = c.newInstance();
 return i;
}
```

where Importable is an interface and the string s is the name of an implementing class.
The compiler says:

```
./Importer.java:33: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Class<capture#964 of ?>
required: java.lang.Class<Importable>
  Class<Importable> c = Class.forName(format(s));
```

thanks for any help!

All the solutions

```
Class<? extends Importable> c = Class.forName(s).asSubclass(Importable.class);
```

and

```
Class<? extends Importable> c = (Class<? extends Importable>) Class.forName(s);
```

and

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(format(s));
Importable i = (Importable)c.newInstance();
```

give this error (that i don't understand):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class C1 
has interface Importable as super class
```

where C1 is actually implementing Importable (so it is theoretically castable to Importable).

Comment: this `IncompatibleClassChangeError`, is it during `forName`? Maybe during `newInstance`? In any case, that's an entirely different question, likely to have nothing to do with generics at all, and you should make a new question for it.

Comment: yes it is, here is the last piece of the stack trace:
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
 at Importer.getRightImportable(Importer.java:33)
 at Importer.importAll(Importer.java:44)
 at Test.main(Test.java:16)

Comment: ask a new question. That's an entirely different issue. This one is practically resolved (perfectly, thanks to doublep).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use a runtime conversion:

```
Class <? extends Importable>  c
    = Class.forName (s).asSubclass (Importable.class);
```

This will bark with an exception at runtime if `s` specifies a class that doesn't implement the interface.

Comment: +1 great way to avoid the ugly cast. I din't know about this one.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
Class<? extends Importable> klaz = Class.forName(s).asSubclass(Importable.class);
```

Here are some snippets to illustrate the problems:

```
Class<CharSequence> klazz = String.class; // doesn't compile!
// "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<String> to Class<CharSequence>"
```

However:

```
Class<? extends CharSequence> klazz = String.class; // compiles fine!
```

So for an `interface`, you definitely need the upper-bounded wildcard. The `asSubclass` is as suggested by doublep.

#### API links

- [`<U> Class<? extends U> asSubclass(Class<U> clazz)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29)

  - Casts this `Class` object to represent a subclass of the class represented by the specified class object. Checks that that the cast is valid, and throws a `ClassCastException` if it is not. If this method succeeds, it always returns a reference to this class object.

#### Related questions

- [What is the difference between `<E extends Number>` and `<Number>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770264/what-is-the-difference-between-e-extends-number-and-number/)

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Generics/Subtyping](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)
- [More fun with wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)

Comment: Works on my install but whines about the unchecked cast. I can't help thinking there's a better way...

Comment: I've found a slightly cleaner way which silences the warning, which I'm about to post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might do the trick:

```
Class<?> c1 = Class.forName(s);
Class<? extends Importable> c = c1.asSubclass(Importable.class);
return c.newInstance();
```

Beware of a `ClassCastException` or `NoClassDefFound` if you pass in the wrong thing. As @polygenelubricants says, if you can figure out some way to avoid `Class.forName` then so much the better!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Class.forName is a static method with the following definition

public static Class forName(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException

Therefore it is not a bound parameter type at all and compiler would definitely throw the cast warning here as it has no way to guarantee the string name of the class would always give you  the implementation of the interface.

If you know for sure that the string name passed into the method would be an implementation of the interface you can use SuppressWarnings annotation. But I dont think ther eis any other cleaner way to use forName with generics

Answer (score 0):

> where Importable is an interface and the string s is the name of an implementing class.

The compiler can't know that, hence the error.

Use a cast. It is easier to cast the constructed object (because that is a checked cast), than the class object itself.

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(s);
Importable i = (Importable) c.newInstance();
return i;
```