# How create instance of generic class with result of Class.forName

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Can I create an instance of a generic class without knowing its type parameter? I have only 'class' type, which have been obtained from the Class.forName (classname);

```
//generic class

public class MappedField<T> extends Field {
    private T value;
    private String sourceName;

public MappedField(String name, String sourceName, FieldType type){
    super(name, type);
    this.sourceName = sourceName;
}    

public MappedField(String name, String sourceName, FieldType type, boolean key){
    super(name, type, key);
    this.sourceName = sourceName;
}
```

}

```
//here's my situation

    String columnName = field.getSourceName() != null ? field.getSourceName() : field.getName();
            Class c = Class.forName(field.getType().getFullClassName());            

            //I need like that if `field.getType() = "Integer"`: `MappedField<Integer> objField = new MappedField<Integer>(field)`;
            MappedField objField = new MappedField(field);

            objField.setValue(getField(c, rset, columnName));            
            object.getValues().add(objField);
```

**EDIT:** 
It's like I have "java.lang.Integer" and want get MappedField

Comment: Refer this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892833/classt-and-static-method-class-forname-drive-me-crazy

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM can you be more specific? It's not look like `Class.forName ("java.lang.Integer").asSubclass (MappedField.class)` give me `MappedField<Integer>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Generic type will erased from the classes and interfaces on successful compilation.On runtime it is not possible to detect the generic type.

Refer the link:
[Use reflection to create a generic parameterized class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373800/use-reflection-to-create-a-generic-parameterized-class-in-java)