# Reflection problem - Type Safety Warning

Tags: java

```
Class<? extends Algorithm> alg = AlgorithmAllFrom9AndLastFrom10Impl.class   
Constructor<Algorithm> c = alg.getConstructors()[0];
```

For "alg.getConstructors()[0];" I am getting a warning in eclipse

> Type safety: The expression of type
>   Constructor needs unchecked conversion
>   to conform to Constructor

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation for `Class<T>.getConstructors()` reveals the issue:

> [`Constructor<?>[] getConstructors()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29): Note that while this method returns an array of `Constructor<T>` objects (that is an array of constructors from this class), the return type of this method is `Constructor<?>[]` and not `Constructor<T>[]` as might be expected. This less informative return type is necessary since after being returned from this method, the array could be modified to hold `Constructor` objects for different classes, which would violate the type guarantees of `Constructor<T>[]`.

Compare this with `Class<T>.getConstructor()` overload:

> [`Constructor<T> getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29)

This overload actually returns `Constructor<T>`.

In your case, since you have `Class<? extends Algorithm> alg`, `alg.getConstructor(parameterTypes)` returns a `Constructor<? extends Algorithm>` (which by the way, can NOT be safely cast to `Constructor<Algorithm>`).

Whenever possible, i.e. when you know the parameter types, you should always prefer `getConstructor(parameterTypes)` to `getConstructors()[arbitraryIndex]`, since with the latter you're never quite guaranteed which constructor will be selected. Selecting based on parameter types is most specific, and as shown here, is also more compiler-friendly with regards to the generic type information.

If by `getConstructors()[0]` you really meant to get the nullary constructor, then simply do this instead:

```
Constructor<? extends Algorithm> nullaryConstructor = alg.getConstructor();
```

---

#### Summary

So your problem was two fold:

- `getConstructors()` returns a `Constructor<?>[]`, meaning all type information are lost
- Even if type information isn't lost (e.g. by using `getConstructor(parameterTypes)` overload), you'd still only get a `Constructor<? extends Algorithm>` at best (not a `Constructor<Algorithm>`).

  - `Class<T>.getConstructor(parameterTypes)` returns a `Constructor<T>`
  - In your case, the type parameter `T` is `? extends Algorithm`

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Generics/More fun with wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)

#### Related questions

- [What is the difference between `<E extends Number>` and `<Number>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770264/what-is-the-difference-between-e-extends-number-and-number/)

---

#### Discussion

It is unfortunate that `getConstructors()` returns an array because as explained in the dcoumentation, because since arrays covariant, this forced the signature to `Constructor<?>`, losing generic type information. The fact that arrays are mutable also means that `getConstructors()` must create a new array instance every time!

```
    System.out.println(int.class.getConstructors().length); // prints "0"
    System.out.println(
        int.class.getConstructors() == int.class.getConstructors()
    ); // prints "false"!
```

Ideally `getConstructors()` should return a `List<Constructor<T>>`, which should be wrapped by [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29); not only would this keep the type information, but `Class<T>` could also then return the same `List` object on every `getConstructors()`.

For more discussion on this subject, read *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays*.

Comment: thanks I used Constructor<? extends Algorithm> c = alg.getConstructor(theArgumentTypes);

Answer (score 0):

Actually without a cast to `Constructor<Algorithm>` I get an error.

One solution is to do `Constructor<?> c = alg.getConstructors()[0];` since that's the type that getConstructors() returns.

Another is to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to that line, basically telling the compiler "I know for sure that this is a `Constructor<Algorithm>`" which the compiler can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

The `Constructor` array returned from `getConstructors()` has an unbounded wildcard type paramter.  You can use:

```
Constructor<?> c = alg.getConstructors()[0];
```

I assume that the reason `getConstructors()` doesn't bound its wildcard is because that would result in a generic array.  Perhaps one of the `getConstructor()` methods is better suited for what you need.