# List of inheriting objects java

Tags: java, list, inheritance

I created a little example. Imagine I have two classes:

```java
public class Neuron {
    ArrayList<Neuron> neighbours = new ArrayList<>();
    int value = 1;

    public Neuron() {

    }

    public void connect(ArrayList<Neuron> directNeighbours) {
        for (Neuron node : directNeighbours) {
            this.neighbours.add(node);
        }
    }

}
```

and a class that inherits from Neuron:

```java
public class SpecialNeuron extends Neuron {

    int value = 2;

    public SpecialNeuron() {

    }
}
```

In my case, I want the inheritance in order to avoid a lot of "if object is special do something" stuff. However, when I am calling:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Neuron> neurons = new ArrayList<>();

    Neuron a = new Neuron();
    Neuron b = new Neuron();
    Neuron c = new Neuron();
    neurons.add(b);
    neurons.add(c);

    a.connect(neurons);

    ArrayList<SpecialNeuron> special = new ArrayList<>();
    SpecialNeuron d = new SpecialNeuron();
    SpecialNeuron e = new SpecialNeuron();
    special.add(d);
    special.add(e);

    a.connect(special); //Error
}
```

it is not possible to use a List(SpecialNeuron) for a List(Neuron) parameter. What is wrong with this call, and is there a proper way to solve that issue?
Furthermore, I could do

```java
ArrayList<Neuron> special = new ArrayList<>();
Neuron d = new SpecialNeuron();
Neuron e = new SpecialNeuron();
special.add(d);
special.add(e);

a.connect(special); //works fine
```

Which works, but denies any usage of functions from the SpecialNeuron class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast a list of inheriting objects to a collection of objects in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754756/how-to-cast-a-list-of-inheriting-objects-to-a-collection-of-objects-in-java)

Comment: You have to either cast the particular SpecialNeurons from Neuron to that class, or you use a method common to all Neurons that you override in class SpecialNeuron. Polymorphism will then call the correct version for you.

Comment: @Jems I implemented empty methods in the Neuron class which will be overwritten in the Special Neuron class. It enables me to call the methods due to Polymorphism. Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: Should I delete the question because it seems that I cant determine a concrete solution rather a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of WildCards in Generic `<? extends T>`.You can read more about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics-vs-extends-object).

Change your method param to this.

```
  public void connect(ArrayList<? extends Neuron> directNeighbours) {
        for (Neuron node : directNeighbours) {
            this.neighbours.add(node);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very interesting feature. It worked for the given example but not for my own project. My fault due to the lack of explaination.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're extending `Neuron` class, but you're not really using inheritance. You should make `value` variable `protected` and set its value in constructor.

```
public class Neuron {
    protected int value;

    public Neuron() {
        this.value = 1;
    }
}

public class SpecialNeuron extends Neuron {
    public SpecialNeuron() {
        this.value = 2;
    }
}
```

Now, your problem is on the line 17 - `ArrayList<SpecialNeuron> special = new ArrayList<>();` - you have List of `SpecialNeuron` objects, that are children of `Neuron` class, so Java knows it contains only objects of class `SpecialNeuron`

In your `connect()` function, you accept only `Neuron` class objects, so in order to make it work, you have to change your `special` list to:

```
ArrayList<Neuron> special = new ArrayList<>();
```

In this List, you can add `Neuron` and `SpecialNeuron` objects and use it as a List of `Neuron` objects.

Comment: You are right but then I can not address methods of the Special Neuron which are unique for that class.